# Fatal error compiling: error: invalid target release: 17

Tags: java, maven, jenkins-pipeline, sonarqube

I am trying to build a project via Jenkins, but I keep on getting this error:

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal
> org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile
> (default-compile) on project my-project: Fatal error compiling: error:
> invalid target release: 17 -> [Help 1]

I have tried assigning source and target versions in pom.xml, wouldn't work.

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>${maven-compiler-plugin.version}</version>
      <configuration>
         <target>17</target>
         <source>17</source>
      </configuration>
</plugin>
```

mvn --version output:

```
Apache Maven 3.8.1 (05c21c65bdfed0f71a2f2ada8b84da59348c4c5d)
Maven home: C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2022.3.3\plugins\maven\lib\maven3
Java version: 17.0.8, vendor: Eclipse Adoptium, runtime: C:\Program Files\Eclipse Adoptium\jdk-17.0.8.7-hotspot
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "windows 10", version: "10.0", arch: "amd64", family: "windows"
```

As a matter of fact, if I specify the source and target of versions as 1.8, it would then build correctly, but the project is using Java 17.

```
   <java.version>17</java.version>
```

What other ways of fixing I could try to make it work?

Comment: You must use Java 17 or newer with maven.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen Could you please elaborate?

Comment: Are you sure that your Jenkins environment is running 17 or later?

Comment: Yeah that's interesting, unfortunately it seems to be Using Java 11 instead of Java 17th. Weird anomaly, as it should actually use 17, as per pipeline setup

Comment: Obviously is the JDK used by the appropriate build on Jenkins not JDK17...

Answer (score 1):

I think the configurations for java 8 with maven-compiler-plugin and java 17 with maven-compiler-plugin is different ways to define it.

For java 8 and lower version it's as below,

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.11.0</version>
    <configuration>
      <source>1.8</source>
      <target>1.8</target>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

For java 9+ version the configurations are as below,

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.11.0</version>
    <configuration>
      <release>8</release>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

References:

- https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/examples/set-compiler-release.html
- https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/examples/set-compiler-source-and-target.html